# Getting `ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs` even after using `np.nan_to_num()`

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I'm getting this `ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs` even after I used `np.nan_to_num()`.

As you can see in the code block below, I wrote a function that puts sentiment scores through the `logit` function to get a normal distribution. I got the `ValueError` above at first so I decided to try using `np.nan_to_num()` on the sentiment scores and then input them into the `pearsonr` function. However, even after that it is still creating the error. When I use `logit` and `np.nam_to_num()` in a separate unit test though and print the output, there are no inf or nan values (note: there were some infs before using `np.nam_to_num()` though, caused by the `logit` function, but they were all successfully replaced in the separate unit test that was printed). I'm not sure what's going on in the loop below though. For reference, `new_all_data` is just a pandas dataframe that I used to store all the various pieces of information. Any help is appreciated!

```
from scipy import special, stats
import numpy as np

def logit_correlate(sentiments, percent_changes):
    normalised_sentiments = special.logit(sentiments)
    normalised_sentiments_fixed = np.nan_to_num(normalised_sentiments)
    r, p_value = stats.pearsonr(normalised_sentiments_fixed, percent_changes)
    return r, p_value

for sentiment in ['weighted_sentiments', 'unweighted_sentiments', 'weighted_sentiments_DBSCAN', 'full_mean', 'full_mean_unrounded', 'full_mode']:
    r_1yr, p_value_1yr = logit_correlate(new_all_data[sentiment], new_all_data['% change 1 year'])
    print(f'{sentiment:10} 1 year r={r_1yr:10} p={p_value_1yr:10}')
```

Edit: I ran another test to make sure I wasn't losing my mind. Here is the modified `logit_correlate` function:

```
def logit_correlate(sentiments, percent_changes):
    normalised_sentiments = special.logit(sentiments)
    normalised_sentiments_fixed = np.nan_to_num(normalised_sentiments)
    print(np.isnan(normalised_sentiments_fixed).any())
    print(np.isinf(normalised_sentiments_fixed).any())
    print(np.isnan(percent_changes.values).any())
    print(np.isinf(percent_changes.values).any())
    r, p_value = stats.pearsonr(normalised_sentiments_fixed, percent_changes)
    return r, p_value
```

As you can see, I checked to make sure there were no nan or inf values in either of the input arrays for the pearson correlation (`pearsonr`). Everything returned false. The function breaks when the `pearsonr` function is called, both the `logit` and `np.nan_to_num()` functions run (I printed their output as well just to make sure). And yet it still is raising the `ValueError`.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the issue, but you are passing `percent_changes` while printing out `percent_changes.values`.

Comment: I used .values because it is a pandas series and I wanted all the values to print. But the pearsonr functions takes in anything array-like so doubt that is the problem.

Comment: Please include the full traceback. `np.nan_to_num` replaces infinity values with some very large numbers, so depending on the math that `pearsonr` performs, it might be that these large number are causing additional `inf`s down the road. Check what happens if you either drop them or set them manually via the `posinf=..., neginf=...` keywords.

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @a_guest `np.nan_to_num` is definitely creating some large numbers (e308 and e-308), maybe those are what's causing the error even though they aren't actually inf? I can try setting manually thanks! Also, can you explai nwhat you mean by including a full traceback? @Warren Weckesser I will try create a min reproducible example with dummy data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`np.nan_to_num`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html) replaces `inf` values with some very large number which can cause additional `inf` later on. [`scipy.stats.pearsonr`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/adc4f4f7bab120ccfab9383aba272954a0a12fb0/scipy/stats/stats.py#L3519) computes the `mean` of the input arrays and already two `inf` in the original array are enough to cause an additional `inf` due to the sum of those large numbers exceeding the valid floating point range:

```
>>> np.nan_to_num(np.array([np.inf, np.inf])).mean()
inf
```

Depending on your needs you could either drop them completely via `x[np.isfinite(x)]` or use the `posinf` and `neginv` keyword arguments of `nan_to_num` in order to replace the `inf` with smaller values.

Comment: Thank you! This makes perfect sense. I can try replacing them with  smaller values if necessary then, thank you again